# why doesn't NHibernate FetchMode.Join work in this scenario?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two entities, C and P.
C is mapped to P in a one-to-one association, with lazy="no-proxy",
like this: (P's mapping:)

```
<one-to-one name="c" class="C" property-ref="P" access="field" lazy="no-proxy"/>
```

P is mapped to C in a many-to-one association, like this: (C's mapping:)

```
<many-to-one name="p" column="PId" class="P" access="field" lazy="no-proxy" not-null="false"/>
```

usually I use lazy fetching, but in some cases I use FetchMode.Join to avoid the N+1 SELECTs problem, like this:

```
criteria.SetFetchMode("p", FetchMode.Join)
```

however, using FetchMode.Join for the C entity performs the query with a left outer join, and then immediately performs N more queries, fetching P's by ID! (profiling courtesy of NHProf)

any idea why this is happening?

---

answering @KLE's question, here's an excerpt from the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

> For a primary key association, add
>   the following mappings to Employee and
>   Person respectively:

```
<one-to-one name="person" class="Person"/>
<one-to-one name="employee" class="Employee" constrained="true"/>
```

> Ensure that the primary keys of the related rows in the PERSON and EMPLOYEE tables are equal. 
>    Alternatively, a foreign key with a
>   unique constraint, from Employee to
>   Person, can be expressed as:

```
<many-to-one name="person" class="Person" column="PERSON_ID" > unique="true"/>
```

> This association can be made
>   bidirectional by adding the following
>   to the Person mapping:

```
<one-to-one name="employee" class="Employee" property-ref="person"/>
```

please let me know if I misunderstood this. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I removed my answer, because it brings nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which version of NHibernate you are using but with 2.1.0 - 2.1.2 i've had some issues regarding FetchModes and complex mappings. I hadn't ran into `property-ref` (which obviously confuses the property walker) but i did have problems with some union classes.

Have you tried setting `lazy="true" / "extra"` and then define `FetchMode.Join` ?